# Calculation of mean in R

Tags: r, mean

How can I calculate the mean, step-by-step, in R?

Comment: `(x[1] + x[2] + x[3])/3` ... Sorry but what exactly is the problem in here? Please notice that "how to do X in R" kind of questions are off-topic on this site (see http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Such questions can be on topic on stackoverflow.com, but your question is very basic and you should rather start with reading some R tutorial or handbook, since there is lots of such materials available.

Comment: Yeah. You are telling the truth but I wasn't find function. Ferdi, gave the necessary response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume an example vector. Furthermore I assume that by mean you understand the 
  [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean).

```
 x <- c(2,4,6,8)
```

Obviously the mean is equal to 5. So this command gives you the mean.

Here is the formula for the arithmetic mean.

A = $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n$ $a_i$

So you can divide split the procedure into three steps.

1. Calculate the sum of the vector x
2. Calculate the number of items in the vector x
3. Divide the sum of the vector x by the number of items in the vector x

Here is the code, which is the respond to this question.

```
`sum(x)/length(x)´
```

Here is a test which shows you that it is equal to the mean (at least for the example).

```
sum(x)/length(x) == mean(x)
```

Comment: thank you. How can write mode function in r?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode